# Do we have a proper serializable for HOCON which would respect the order or does a inline replacement in java?

Tags: java, configuration, config, hocon

I am developing an application in java where it has a config file(I am choosing HOCON, if we have other option please let me know which meets my requirement ) and a UI for editing the config file.

Users can either edit the config file directly or can use the UI.
The config file can have comments.

If users are using UI to edit the file, I need to update the config file, when they hit save.

I am using [lightbend/config](https://github.com/lightbend/config) for reading and writing the config file.

```
ConfigRenderOptions renderOpts = ConfigRenderOptions.defaults().setOriginComments(false).setJson(false);
    String writeString= tsConfig.root().render(renderOpts);
```

But the problem with the writing is it doesn't maintain the order of parameter and comments are messed up.
See the below image:

[image]

My requirement is to have a writer which can maintain the comments and parameter order because as you can see it's not user friendly if some comments are lost .

Is it possible with lightbend/config or are there any other config reader &writer which can meet my requirement?

I am even ready to use  other config formats other than HOCON, if we have a reader and writer which can meet my requirement.

As my config requirement is complex, property file would not be a great choice.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my own question:

https://github.com/lightbend/config/issues/699